# DWR return object from server who to accept it in javascript code

Tags: javascript, dwr

i have a class mymessage in which to feilds of string type whose getter and setter are also present in class.in mymessage class their is a method name getdata in this method i m setting
the string by calling setmethod of the string and return the object who can i get data in the client side from getter method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is Bean Naming convention problems please use the small cases instead of large cases.